# The meaning of the sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of this sentence?:

> I think few will be found to gainsay the assertion that where he trod,
>   his daughter need not be ashamed to follow.

Source: There is no Death

I think the daughter is following someone, but I don't know the meaning of the first sentence.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is extremely flowery and convoluted English but I think that it is grammatically correct. What it means is that if the daughter follows her father's example (in whatever aspect of life we are talking about) then few people could (reasonably) criticise her. The implication is that the father is a good man, so that the daughter cannot be criticised for following his ways. Such a thing would not be said unless there had in fact been some criticism of the daughter: what is written in the sentence quoted is a rebuttal of that criticism.